# E-mail like rich text input

Tags: plugins, input, rtf

How do I implement an e-mail like text area input? Where the users can upload images, format text, etc.

Like when you ask a question here, it gives you option to format text, input HTML or add images.

Comment: Try googling it. There are a lot of solutions out there. When you encounter problems, you can post more specific questions here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use one of the many freely available WYSIWYG editors.

A couple of the more popular ones are:

- CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/
- TinyMCE: http://www.tinymce.com/

You can explore alternatives using [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/fckeditor/).

If your users are more technical, they may prefer a Markdown syntax.